# Fade ImageView edge to transparent

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview, fade

I have an ImageView with a photo user selected from Gallery. It's on the bottom of the container and above it I have an EditText. Now, what I want to do is to fade the top edge to transparent (or white, doesn't matter, will look the same). Here's a preview:

[image: preview]

I achieved the result by placing another ImageView with a white-to-transparent gradient above the selected image but, well, it doesn't look good. Is there any way to fade the image from XML or Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking some thing like bitmap reflection effect.It can be done using canvas,paint and shader.. I have got great tutorial for that.Check the link below

http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/12/android-reflections-with-bitmaps.html

Comment: You linked to this question ;)

Comment: The link is broken.